CS1061 Error: 'RegressionCatalog.RegressionTrainers' does not contain a definition for 'FastTree'
The problem arises from attempting to use the FastTree regression trainer in ML.NET, specifically within the context of the RegressionTrainers class. Despite importing the necessary namespaces and following the documentation, the compiler is unable to recognize the FastTree method, leading to the CS1061 error.
I attempted to use the FastTree regression trainer from the RegressionTrainers class in ML.NET for building a regression model. I expected the code to compile without errors and to successfully train the model using the FastTree algorithm. However, the compiler threw a CS1061 error, indicating that it couldn't find the FastTree method within the RegressionTrainers class

